# Problems with UIActionSheet on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiactionsheet

I'm making an application compatible for iPhone and iPad and I'm showing a picker in a actionsheet as follows:

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Day / Month"
                                          delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];

picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,0,0)];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[actionSheet addSubview:picker];

[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
[actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320,469)];
```

This works well for iPhone, but for the iPad version with the same code and leaving aside those who are different dimensions gives me the following error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not
>   satisfying: view != nil'

At this line:

```
[actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
```

I've tried with showInView:self.view , self.Window, self.view.superview but nothing...

I want to know what gives that error and will not let me do it the same way... thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An action sheet is transformed to a pop-over on the iPad. There are two methods to display a pop-over-

```
 - (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view
 permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections
 animated:(BOOL)animated;

 - (void)presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item
 permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections
 animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Guessing from this, I think you can try using one of the following methods for presenting the action sheet-

```
- (void)showFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item animated:(BOOL)animated 
- (void)showFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view animated:(BOOL)animated
```

instead of using `showInView:`.